# highchart set fill color

Tags: highcharts

I have a highchart that I am using the select and unselect for a bar chart.
I need to change the fiull color when the bar is selected and keep the current color. (I am only changing the border color)

It seem I can use the color property but specifying null there doesnt do the trick.
Is there any way to do this without the API calls. (config options)

Here is what I am doint now

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        allowPointSelect: false,
        states: {
            select: {
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#595E61'
                color: null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you try color: transparent?

Comment: can you knock up a jsfiddle?

Comment: yes here it is:http://www.highcharts.com/jsbin/edumap/7/edit#javascript,live

Comment: do you want all the bars to be green?

Comment: No. Imagine each bar has diffrent color. Selecting it will leave its color and change its border color

Answer (score 0):

try this - it will (hopefully) highlight the selected item as yellow

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        marker: {
            states: {
                select: {
                    fillColor: 'yellow',
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: '#595E61'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-states-select-fillcolor/) for an example of it in action (it's a line graph).

Comment: No guys. not working. I can specify like you mentined any color but I want to keep the color from my series.

Comment: and what is the color from your series?

Comment: where? you haven't provided a hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does the trick for me: http://www.highcharts.com/jsbin/edumap/2/edit

Could the problem be that you set allowPointSelect to false?

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        states: {
            select: {
                borderColor: 'red',
                color: null
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: No It doesn't.My bars are not blue since I am using a series and add colors to it. So when trying your code it becomes blue.

Comment: var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {renderTo: 'container',type: 'column'},
    xAxis: {        categories: 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']},plotOptions: {
        column: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            states: {
                select: {
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    color: null
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data:[{ color: '#00FF00', y: 20 }, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the color of the point in selected state.

```
data:[{ color: '#00FF00', y: 20, states: {select: {color: '#00FF00'}} }, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
```

Here is a demo:

> http://www.highcharts.com/jsbin/edumap/14/edit#javascript,live